# How do I rename a key in a Map Object, while keeping the value and the other keys and values the same?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
bookMap = new Map()
bookMap = Map(3) {
  'Horror': [
    { id: 9798721052927, title: 'Dracula', author: 'Brahm Stoker' },
    { id: 9798721052928, title: 'Dracula 2', author: 'Brahm Stoker' }
  ],
  'Romance': [
    { id: 9798721052933, title: 'Love Story', author: 'Brahm Stoker' }
  ],
  'Comedy': [ { id: 9797221052931, title: 'Ha Story', author: 'Brahm Stoker' } ]
}

const renameKey = (oldKey, newKey, { [oldKey]: old, ...others }) => ({
  [newKey]: old,
  ...others
})

nbm = renameKey('Horror', 'Cusisine', { ['Horror']: bookMap.get('Horror'), ...bookMap })
```

[image: output]

What do I put as ...others to get the ouput as bookMap with all 3 keys, not just the newly changed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is designed for an object, not for a `Map`. A map destructured into an array of arrays. If you want to achieve the same functionality you can use a method like below :

```
const renameKey = (oldKey: string, newKey: string, map: Map<string, any>) => {
  const old = map.get(oldKey);
  const rest = [...map].filter(r => r[0] !== oldKey);
  return new Map(
    [[newKey, old],
    ...rest]);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBARg9jDWBZAhgBwgXggOxAdwhVQAoBtAKAglIHIAJGAJ0aZoBprKqIBvCASwAmALggBOAOxiAHBIBMARgAMAVjli5EjmH5hQomgBFGyAMYBXYMnYRk5sAAsmBgEImHAWwgBlMAhCMNBAAvmxcVHxCopIy8spqGtLauvoQRiYWVhByNnaOzmluyJ4+fvABQcFcALrVYVS0AEowHsjYpiA2FNy8AiLiUrKKquoAzKPJeiAGADIwAG4gpUwAnrn2Toyu7l6+-oEhNXVctADCLSCCaxykkf0x8sMJowqTqfTIy4zXthsFNEUSntygdgrVyNUAJQAbnI5FMMGwAGdIKZMLwuPQmCxAqJutw7tFBnERhotBAdFMDMYzJZrBw8pttsVdmUKiF6gS+kTYk91HIkhSUtM0jTMp8cgy-ltCjtliDKjVOTRmq12p08eFelEBrz4mMJkKqWk5osvj9Gf9Aaz9oqqMcqDRzh5Lms8YTdY99WIXm8RR9zet8jKAXLgeyweRgrD4YiURBGCBsMgXQBpEArOTo4gwYCCdMrUQoxj8bAAcw4uDwBaLYBL5Y4fFIufzGeqohbHAAdD2YI4AkiQpDMAA+CDEHgnKsF9sQTtcHtdvsOAdRyFwjcI5GQbBQLxYRPJtMZuTELHMVgcJ3mJH8W+4GymGFwrfxw8pkAF7MtmsQYuliscHwX9-wbCBWlQUQiAAHlAwC2hWEdhwwMdJyoV9IBbdEIK7MtwBzPMC2fdC40gRN4ywUhFwg6ouwAM34YAwACYhGFHBNSCUaoIAAQgwLAfwzYiE3AcxGGwICCCIYgtVIUhpwzDgWwdbhF3IsAoVhKpY2RXMQC7YAYDLYhdw8Z8dPjAAvdF32PFYzwYC9AivU4bzvUtOg4WAECIZ9Xz0gyjOISyYSAA)